# How I can show http 404 with djangofilterbackend?

Tags: django, python-3.x

django rest framework is showing http 202 ok when I set a wrong value and I want to show http 404 on the api django rest framework, when set a wrong value in djangofilterbackend but I don't know how to implement it.

my views.py:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Producto
from .serializers import ProductoSerializer
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend


class ProductoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['Codigo_Producto']
    queryset = Producto.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductoSerializer
```

my serializers.py:

```py
from .models import Producto
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets



class ProductoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Nombre_Producto = serializers.SerializerMethodField
    class Meta:
        model = Producto
        fields = [
            'id',
            'Nombre_Producto',
            'Codigo_Producto',
            'Precio_sugerido',
            'stock',
        ]

    def get_Producto_name(self,obj:Producto):
        return obj.Producto.get_full_name()
```

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from rest_framework import routers
from GestionadorApp.views import ProductoViewSet

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('Producto', ProductoViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found is overriding the filter backend to ensure that the parameters are what I want else raise a error Http404.

to show a solution I had to take part of code from [Django Filter Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296939/django-filter-backend)

```
from rest_framework import filters
from django.http import Http404

class ObjektFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    allowed_fields = ['username', 'email']

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        flt = {}
        for param in request.query_params:

            #put your logic here
            if request.query_params[param] is None:
                raise Http404 

            for fld in self.allowed_fields:
                if param.startswith(fld):
                    flt[param] = request.query_params[param]

        return queryset.filter(**flt)


class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [ObjektFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ['username', 'email']
```

In another hand you may override the get_queryset method to ensure data too.

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ['username', 'email']

    def get_queryset(self):

        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)

        if username is None:
            raise http404

        return self.queryset
```

[django rest framework filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

Comment: there is any other step on urls ? I am trying to, but geting this error AttributeError: type object 'ProductoViewSet' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'. thanks for answer !

Comment: check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721089/django-viewset-has-not-attribute-get-extra-actions

Comment: you should mark your question as solve if my answer help you :P

Comment: sorry, I am new in stackoverflow xD